# content gets saved as nil rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have run into a rather unusual situation and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening:

I have a `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And a `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :content
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope{order('created_at DESC')}

  #validations
  validates(:content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140})
  validates(:user_id, presence: true)
end
```

My migration for posts looks like this:

```
require_relative '20150405091935_create_posts'
class FixPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    revert CreatePosts #this was the original migration w/o a user reference

    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

- The schema generated seems to be in order
- post validations are in place and work fine (my specs are passing
  and I have done some manual testing in the console)

**The issue**

I create a `post`

```
user = User.first
user.posts.create(content: "This is a post.")
=> true
```

However when I print it out I get the following:

```
#<Post:0x007fc1a0f1d628
  id: 1,
  user_id: 1,
  content: nil,
  created_at: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 19:45:38 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 19:45:38 UTC +00:00>]
```

The content is lost and returns a `nil`.

What is going on here? Am I missing something?

Any help will be appreciated!Thank you for your time.

Please let me know if any additional info is required. You can also see the entire code base on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/arumoy-shome/prilepins_strength_program).

Comment: Why are you using "attr_accessor :content"? Try remove this line.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `attr_accessor :content` from your `Post` model as it sets `content` as `virtual attribute` – model attribute that is not persisted to the database .